# UFT: Could not execute because the application was not found or a compatible .NET SDK is not installed

Tags: .net, uft14

I am using the UFT One Azure DevOps extension to execute the next tasks

```
  - task: PublishTestResults@2
    inputs:
      testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
      testResultsFiles: '$(UFT_WORK)\res\Report_$(Build.BuildNumber)\junit_report.xml'
      failTaskOnFailedTests: true
    continueOnError: true
    displayName: 'Junit.'
```

but I get this error:

```
Could not execute because the application was not found or a compatible .NET SDK is not installed.
Possible reasons for this include:
* You intended to execute a .NET program:
The application '--version' does not exist.
* You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
It was not possible to find any installed .NET SDKs.
Install a .NET SDK from:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

I have tried to validate if the .net sdk is installed with the following commands:

```
dotnet --version
```

> Could not execute because the application was not found or a
> compatible .NET SDK is not installed. Possible reasons for this
> include:
>
> - You intended to execute a .NET program: The application '--version' does not exist.
> - You intended to execute a .NET SDK command: It was not possible to find any installed .NET SDKs. Install a .NET SDK from:
>   https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

`dotnet --list-sdks` that returns me an empty list

I validated in the environment variables and I see that the server has these 2 routes configured in the path

```
$env:Path -split ';'
```

> C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet

> C:\Program Files\dotnet

Also the executable dotnet.exe is in both directories

```
where.exe dotnet
```

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe

> C:\Program Files(x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe

Could it be that the path is conflicting because it has both routes or what else could I validate?